# Regularized cost function with very large λ

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Consider the cost function with regularization in machine learning:

[image]

Why will the parameter θ towards to zero when we set the parameter λ to be very large?

Comment: You are trying to *minimize* a cost function. If you make λ very large, the left term will be much smaller and *vanish* in practice (as the right side is much much larger). That leaves you with minimizing the right side of the equation, which tends to the solution of setting θ as smaller as possible (and centered at 0 as the sum is squared), thus, making it tend towards 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regularized cost function is penalized by the size of the parameters θ.

**The regularization term dominates the cost in case `λ → +inf`**

It is worth noting that when λ is very large, most of the cost will be coming from the regularization term `λ * sum (θ²)` and not the actual cost `sum((h_θ - y)²)`, hence in that case it's mostly about minimizing the regularization term `λ * sum (θ²)` by tending θ towards 0 (`θ → 0`)

**Why minimizing `λ * sum (θ²)` results in `θ → 0`**

Consider the regularization term `λ * sum (θ²)`, to minimize this term the only solution is to push `sum(θ²) → 0`. (`λ` is a positive constant, and the `sum` term is also positive)

And since `θ` terms are squared (`θ²` is always positive), the only way is to push the `θ` parameters towards 0. Hence `sum(θ²) → 0` means `θ → 0`

**So to sum up, in this case of very large λ:**

Minimizing the cost function is mostly about minimizing `λ * sum (θ²)`, which requires minimizing `sum (θ²)`, which requires `θ → 0`

**Some intuition to answer the question in the comment:**

Think of λ as a parameter for you to tell how much of a regularization you want to happen. E.g. if on the extreme you set λ to 0, then your cost function is not regularized at all. If you set λ to a lower number then you get less of a regularization.

And vice versa, the more you increase λ, the more your asking your cost function to regularized, so the smaller the parameters θ will have to be in order to minimize the regularized cost function.

**Why do we use θ² in the regularization sum rather than θ？**

Because the goal is to have small θ (less prone to overfitting).
If the regularization term uses θ instead of θ² in the sum, 
you can end up with **large θ values that cancel each other**,
e.g. θ_1 = 1000000 and θ_2 = -1000001, the `sum(θ)` here is -1 which is small, vs if you took `sum(|θ|)` (absolute value) or `sum(θ²)` (squared) you'd end up with a very big value.

In that case you may end up overfitting because of large θ values that escaped the regularization because the terms cancel each other out.

Comment: so ,what's the meaning of λ? the bigger λ ,the smaller θ?

Comment: but i don't konw why the more i increase λ the smaller the parameters θ?i hope you can explain in mathematic.

Comment: @C.J you have to take into account the algorithm that figures out θ (namly, gradient descent). It repeatedly tries ever smaller values of θ until J(θ) stays the same (when it is said to _converge_). If for a moment we simplify the formula's terms as `J(θ) = sum(something) + λ * sum(θ^2)` it becomes apparent that whenver λ is very big the only way to make the result smaller and smaller is to get `sum(θ^2)` closer and closer to 0. I'm assuming `sum(something) << λ`.

Comment: i get it,thanks your specific explanation,but the another question i want to ask you,why we use θ^2 as regularization rather than θ？

Comment: θ^2 ensures the result is always positive

Answer (score 1):

Hi very late to discussion but I just started going through that course and here is what I understood.

Basically, Andrew is trying to convert a polynomial equation to a quadratic equation and by doing that he is penalizing few theta parameters, by equating them to zero, which avoids the problem of overfitting as you now have an equation which has understood important features and has neglected non important one's.

However, we also need to adjust the cost function. The cost value is ideally zero for an overfitting equation, which is not correct. So we are adding [image: the [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

If you look closely, this is starting from j to n and the other part, 
  [image]

starts from i to n.

**Whats is the problem with large lambda?**

With a large lambda, cost will explode and curve will now underfit. It is important to chose the right value of lambda. If you happen to chose large lambda, then it is also important to chose very very small theta so that cost function is still in control. Its a question of how much of cost we want to inflate at the end of the day which controls this values of lambda and theta.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that the summation (after lambda) doesn't include theta(0). Hope this helps!