# In the regularization,why we use θ^2 rather than θ？

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

[image]

The regularization is lambda*sum(θ^2)

Comment: @Ami how do you know he meant |theta|? Yes, it makes sense to use |theta| as opposed to "theta", but claiming what someone else problem is is rather a shoot in the dark.

Comment: @lejlot In retrospect, you're right. (It still is a bad question placed in the wrong stackexchange, though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>I've [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052558/regularized-cost-function-with-very-large-%CE%BB/39052604#39052604) this in your previous question (see last paragraph), but I'll try again.</sub>

The problem regularizing with `sum(θ)` is that you may have θ parameters that cancel each other

Example:

```
θ_1 = +1000000
θ_2 = -1000001
```

The `sum(θ)` here is +1000000 -1000001 = -1 which is small

The `sum(θ²)` is 1000000² + (-1000001)² which is very big.

If you use `sum(θ)` you may end up without regularization (which was the goal) because of large θ values that escaped the regularization because the terms cancel each other out.

You may use `sum(|θ|)` depending on your search/optimisation algorithm. But I know θ² (L2 norm) to be popular and works well with gradient descent.

Comment: Another reason is that it provides additional regularization by penalizing coefficients which are large. If θ is big, then θ^2 would be big and hence large values of θ will get penalized. So, this regularization favours smaller theta values than `sum(|θ|)`